# Converting Code from VB to Python in Map Algebra

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, map-algebra, vb

I have a problem with Map Algebra in ArcMap 10 to convert some codes made by VB, so I need to convert it to python to work in ArcMap 10 without problem.

How do I deal with map algebra in ArcMap 10?

the code:

```
con([Direction to univer] > 0 & [Direction to univer] <= 180,[Direction to univer] + 180,[Direction to univer] - 180)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do the processing directly in python without much fuss:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

direction = Raster("direction-to-univer.tif")

output = con((direction > 0) & (direction <= 180), direction + 180, direction)
output.save("conned.tif")
```